# Message gets sent before both functions are completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-synchronization

I am using the pubchem-access module for a Node.JS bot to retrieve certain chemical properties for a compound and then sending them to Telegram. I want to combine several properties and get a CAS identifier as well, but retrieving the CAS identifier is a seperate function (see: http://mmmalik.github.io/pubchem-access/#request).
I have tried to combine both into one message by just putting the desired functions after each other:

```
            case 'prop':
            var cas = ""
            pubchem
                .setName(commandText)
                .getCas()
                .execute(function(data, status) {
                    if (status != 1) {
                        cas = status;
                    } else {
                        cas = data
                    }
                });


            pubchem

                .setName(commandText)
                .getProperties(["IUPACName", "MolecularWeight", "MolecularFormula",
                    "CanonicalSMILES"
                ])
                .execute(function(data) {
                    msg.answer(
                        "IUPAC name: " + data.IUPACName + ",\nCAS :" + cas +
                        ",\nMW: " + data.MolecularWeight.toFixed(2) + ",\nFormula: " + data.MolecularFormula +
                        ", \nSMILES: " + data.CanonicalSMILES);
                });

            break;
```

What I get when doing this, is that sometimes the CAS property isn't yet found while the others have, so sometimes the message get's sent without a CAS.

What can I do to guarantee the message to be sent only after all the wanted properties are retrieved?

Sorry I'm having trouble with the code layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the second request in a function and call it when the callback function of `execute` is called

```
pubchem
.setName(commandText)
.getCas()
.execute(function(data, status) {
    var cas = !Object.is(status,1) ? status : data;
    doSecondRequest(cas);
});

function doSecondRequest(cas){
    pubchem
    .setName(commandText)
    .getProperties(["IUPACName", "MolecularWeight", "MolecularFormula","CanonicalSMILES"])
    .execute(function(data) {
        msg.answer(
            "IUPAC name: " + data.IUPACName + ",\nCAS :" + cas +
            ",\nMW: " + data.MolecularWeight.toFixed(2) + ",\nFormula: " + data.MolecularFormula +
            ", \nSMILES: " + data.CanonicalSMILES);
        });
}
```

Or use `promises` to handle the asynchronous calls

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    pubchem
    .setName(commandText)
    .getCas()
    .execute((data, status) => {
        var cas = !Object.is(status,1) ? status : data;
        resolve(cas);
    });
};

promise.then((cas) => {
    pubchem
    .setName(commandText)
    .getProperties(["IUPACName", "MolecularWeight", "MolecularFormula","CanonicalSMILES"])
    .execute((data) => {
        msg.answer(
            "IUPAC name: " + data.IUPACName + ",\nCAS :" + cas +
            ",\nMW: " + data.MolecularWeight.toFixed(2) + ",\nFormula: " + data.MolecularFormula +
            ", \nSMILES: " + data.CanonicalSMILES);
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, both options work perfectly. I knew it had something to do with asynchronity but I've never heard of Promise, so I'll read up on that.